# Django multiple foreign key, Same related name

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I would like to create a model(1) with multiple foreign keys to the same other model(2).
I want these foreign keys to have the same `related_name` because each foreign key will point to difference instances of model(2), because I need one reversed relation for all foreign keys.

Maybe an example will be more explicit :

```
class Parent(Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Child(Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    father = models.ForeignKey(Parent, related_name='children')
    mother = models.ForeignKey(Parent, related_name='children')
```

How can I do that ?

I already know an ugly way to do so :

```
class Parent(Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    @property
    def children(self):
         # Pick the existing one in fields 'children_1' or 'children_2'

class Child(Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    father = models.ForeignKey(Parent, related_name='children_1')
    mother = models.ForeignKey(Parent, related_name='children_2')
```

Comment: You cant have same related names. There is no other way around than the one you mentioned.

Comment: Although, if you are willing to change your DB Schema, then you can replace fields `mother` and `father` with `parents` as a `ManyToManyField` and add a `type` field in `Parent` model with choices as `M` or `F`, corresponding to `Mother` and `Father`. Then, you can have the `related_name` of `parents` as `children`.

Comment: @SachinKukreja: using a many-to-may relation *can* be an option, it can however require *extra* logic to enforce that every child has a mother and father (and not zero parents, one parent, two fathers, two mothers, three mothers and two fathers, etc.).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes, that is the disadvantage, only if you weren't expecting a child to have multiple mothers and/or fathers.

Comment: @SachinKukreja: I agree, it of course depends a bit on the "scope" of the application. In certain countries children *can* have more parents (well there are two *biological*, but even that nowadays might change), but other people can be listed as parents that have the same legal obligations.

Answer (score 12):

The `related_names` can not be the same, since this would introduce confusion: an object that is related *through* the `mother` is not (exactly) the same as an object related through the `father`.

You can alter your modeling (for example by introducing a `ManyToManyField` with the `Parent`, and for example add extra data in the relation about the sex of the parent). But a disavantage of this approach is that now, you no longer set the *cardinality* of the relation to 2: it means a `Child` can (by desing) have zero parents, one parent, two parents, three parents, or more. Furthermore it could be possible that a child has two mothers, or two fathers, or two mothers and three fathers. So it can result in a lot of extra logic to prevent certain cases. Note that in some countries that is possible: in some countries extra people can be listed as "parents", and they have the same legal rights and duties as a parent.

You can however define such property to obtain the `children`, by making a query to fetch all `Child` objects where the `mother`, or the `father` is `self`:

```
from django.db.models import Q

class Parent(Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    @property
    def children(self):
         return Child.objects.filter(Q(mother=self) | Q(father=self))
```

You could for example name the related names `'father_of'` and `'mother_of'` such that you can query `some_parent.mother_of` to obtain children where the `some_parent` is the `mother_of`. This could be useful if you for example would want to list a table with mothers and their children, or if you would make an application where it is possible that `Parent`s change gender.

If you however want to have strict `Father`s and `Mother`s, then it might be beneficial to define two *separate* models. The advantage is that you can both name the `related_name`s `'children'` then, and furthermore *by design* you check that the `father` of a `Child` is a male (and similar for a `mother` being female).