# DRF nested serializer is not serializing data

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am trying to serialize related models for an API view.

```
class Dashboard(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(IamUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='dashboards')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    position = models.IntegerField()
    config = models.CharField(max_length=5000, blank=True, null=True)

class WidgetLayout(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(IamUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='widgets')
    dashboard = models.ForeignKey(Dashboard, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='widgets')
    type = models.ForeignKey(Widget, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    position = models.IntegerField()
    width = models.IntegerField()
    config = models.CharField(max_length=5000, blank=True, null=True)
```

with the following serializers

```
class WidgetLayoutSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = WidgetLayout
        fields = ['id', 'type', 'position', 'width', 'config']


class DashboardSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        widgets = WidgetLayoutSerializer(many=True)
        model = Dashboard
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'position', 'config', 'type', 'widgets']
```

The view calls the serializers like this:

```
        dashboards = request.user.dashboards.all()
        serializer = DashboardSerializer(dashboards, many=True)
```

**The expected output would be a list of Widgets in their JSON serialization for each Dashboard, however, I get only a list of Widget-IDs.** I discovered that, if i remove the `widgets = WidgetLayoutSerializer(many=True)`, the result is the same, so I suspect, the serializer is not being used or referenced properly. I went through https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#example and tried to spot any difference, but could not find it.

Adding the prefetch_related for the widgets to the .all() in the view made no difference.

depth=1 is not really helpful, as I want to specify each serializer explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely not correct that 2 fields have the same related_name:

```py
user = models.ForeignKey(IamUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='widgets')
dashboard = models.ForeignKey(Dashboard, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='widgets')
```

Remove `widgets` from `user`.

Also the field should be a base class property, not a `Meta` class property.

```py
class DashboardSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    widgets = WidgetLayoutSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Dashboard
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'position', 'config', 'type', 'widgets']
```

Everything else seems good for me.

Comment: Thank you, moving the Serializer up to the base class solved it!
Regarding to the related name: isn't that the name the set of THIS model will have in the referenced model?

Comment: Yes, it will be used in reverse relations. So you can access a `user` from `WidgetLayout` simply by calling `.user` on a WidgetLayout instance. But if you want to access all the widgets from `Dashboard` you cannot do this, because the key is on the "other" side of the relationship. So that's where `related_name` is used. So `dashboard.widgets` will give you the widgets. It cannot be the same: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51988340/9016625

Comment: That link clarifies it. Thanks for taking the time!